# Prioritising Certain Flink Operations over Others

Tags: java, etl, apache-flink

I am using `Flink v1.4.0`.

I am leveraging the batch API to do some ETL, where I have a `DataSet<Employee >` where the `Employee` is of the following form:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private String name;
private double baseSalary;
private double bonus;
private double totalComp;

...
}
```

Assume there is a constructor, setters and getters for all variables.

Now, I have a number of operations being applied in, what I think is, a sequential manner, according to which I am trying to enrich a `DataSet<Employee> employees` as follows:

```
...
DataSet<String> employees = env.fromCollection(employeesList);

DataSet<Employee> initEmployees = employees.map(new InitMapFunction());

DataSet<Employee> employeesEnrichedWithSalaryData = initEmployees.map(new SalaryMapFunction(salaryEnrichmentData));

DataSet<Employee> employeesEnrichedWithBonusData = employeesEnrichedWithSalaryData.map(new BonusMapFunction(bonusEnrichmentData));

DataSet<Employee> finalEmployeesData = employeesEnrichedWithSalaryData.map(new TotalCompMapFunction());
...
```

Assume that somewhere in my package I have the following `MapFunction` implementations:

```
final class InitMapFunction implements MapFunction<String, Employee>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Employee map(String name) {

        Employee employee = Employee.newBuilder().build();
        employee.setName(name)
        return employee;
    }
}

final class SalaryMapFunction implements MapFunction<Employee, Employee>, Serializable {

    private Map<String, double> mapOfEmployeeVsSalary;

    SalaryMapFunction(Map<String, double> mapOfEmployeeVsSalary) {
        this.mapOfEmployeeVsSalary = mapOfEmployeeVsSalary;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee map(Employee employee) {

        if(mapOfEmployeeVsSalary.containsKey(employee.getName())) {
           employee.setSalary(mapOfEmployeeVsSalary.get(employee.getName()))
        }

        return employee;
    }
}

final class BonusMapFunction implements MapFunction<Employee, Employee>, Serializable {

    private Map<String, double> mapOfEmployeeVsBonus;

    SalaryMapFunction(Map<String, double> mapOfEmployeeVsBonus) {
        this.mapOfEmployeeVsBonus = mapOfEmployeeVsBonus;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee map(Employee employee) {

        if(mapOfEmployeeVsBonus.containsKey(employee.getName())) {
           employee.setBonus(mapOfEmployeeVsBonus.get(employee.getName()))
        }

        return employee;
    }
}

final class TotalCompMapFunction implements MapFunction<Employee, Employee>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Employee map(Employee employee) {
        employee.setTotalComp(employee.getSalary + employee.getBonus);
        return employee;
    }
}
```

The question is: will the final `DataSet` (finalEmployeesData) contain the correct value? I know I can do it all in one go, but that's not the point of this question. The functionality of the code I have implemented requires that the enrichment takes place in distinct steps. I have identified cases where specific fields were not enriched with the correct values when processing datasets as elaborated above. I understand/suspect this is due to lazy evaluation and relies on optimisations that `Flink` goes through in order to calculate the optimal execution sequence (identify independent operations etc). Is this correct?

Finally, how can I guarantee that a certain operation takes precedence over another? And will the output change if a chain these operations together as follows?

```
DataSet<Employee> finalEmployessData = env.fromCollection(employeesList)
                  .map(new InitMapFunction())
                  .map(new SalaryMapFunction(salaryEnrichmentData))
                  .map(new BonusMapFunction(bonusEnrichmentData))
                  .map(new TotalCompMapFunction());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink does not change the order of operations. If you define the program as

```
DataSet<Y> result = input
  .map(new Map1())
  .map(new Map2())
```

then `Map2()` will always be applied on the result of `Map1()`.

Also it does not make a difference whether you apply the functions one-by-one on different objects or in a fluent style as in your last code snippet.

You said, that you observed cases where some value would not be correctly set. Assuming that the code you run is not exactly the same as shown here, one reason might be how Flink connects operators and how it ships records between operators. In certain situations (such as sequences of map functions), Flink passes records by method calls to avoid serialization costs. We call this *chaining of functions* . Chained functions are fused into a single operator (you can see that in the web UI for instance). Obviously the functions must be careful about how they interact with objects that they received and emit. Otherwise the same record might be modified by two function at the same time. I'd recommend to have a close look at the section about [object reusage](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/#operating-on-data-objects-in-functions) in Flink's documentation.